# How to assign svg image to class in angular

Tags: css

I have svg image and I am trying to add image for i using class. But the image is not working. So, How to add the image for i class in angular.

```
 <ul class="nav-list">
  <li>
  <a class="active-nav-item">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="home" title="Home"></i>
    <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.home{
background-image:url(assets/images/home.svg);
width:12px;
height:12px;
}
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcltvq-kmsuau?file=app%2Ficon-svg-example.html

Comment: Are you sure the element has a width and height?

Comment: @Kokodoko: Yes, the element have width and height. But not working

Comment: An `i` element does not have width and height. You should add `display:block` if you need an empty element that still has a width and height. You can always check the width and height with `border:1px solid red`. The other problem is that your stackblitz won't load from the assets folder. If you use an online SVG it works: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg`

Answer (score 0):

For width and height to take effect the element should be inline-block. Also make sure you have placed the SVG file in correct src folder.

```
.home {
display:inline-block;
background-image:url(assets/images/home.svg);
width:12px;
height:12px;
}
```